# Matching two distributions and subsampling

Tags: distributions, matching

This should be a simple problem that I have no idea how to solve it.

I have two datasets in R each with 3 columns (ID, Age and a response to a drug). I want to subsample both these datasets and build 2 new datasets where the distributions of the age would be comparable between the two) as it stands at the moment the distributions of the populations are very different.

```
> dput(fake_a)
structure(list(id = c(43L, 98L, 4L, 42L, 19L, 77L, 13L, 61L, 
49L, 120L, 114L, 110L, 137L, 5L, 130L, 32L, 81L, 123L, 105L, 
67L, 51L, 93L, 63L, 78L, 109L, 106L, 24L, 59L, 10L, 102L, 132L, 
122L, 62L, 38L, 48L, 72L, 76L, 40L, 121L, 100L, 21L, 112L, 50L, 
73L, 134L, 46L, 97L, 53L, 118L, 89L, 8L, 55L), Age = c(9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 31L, 31L), Drug = c(7.73e-06, 
0.035568668, 0.039533448, 0.06821241, 0.110051285, 0.193094585, 
0.885769541, 3.51e-15, 4.08e-08, 0.002390798, 0.00415961, 0.010541549, 
1.61e-07, 0.000424592, 0.004733639, 0.01759811, 0.176457314, 
5.29e-05, 0.020455286, 0.034732968, 7.19e-07, 0.002856616, 0.083563445, 
0.109652418, 0.000162434, 0.004633846, 0.015832868, 0.016836652, 
0.041129732, 0.054431933, 0.067120466, 0.126428818, 0.23164155, 
0.000672928, 0.02102658, 0.043945272, 0.049087889, 9.28e-10, 
0.000451081, 0.013083765, 0.074481808, 0.082457527, 0.111466728, 
0.08553393, 0.121672889, 0.168398305, 0.00650793, 0.071334948, 
0.148817407, 0.041950437, 0.066219363, 0.227958055)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))

> dput(fake_b)
structure(list(id = c(13L, 116L, 9L, 71L, 34L, 96L, 29L, 15L, 
18L, 58L, 84L, 6L, 94L, 66L, 86L, 127L, 91L, 119L, 117L, 31L), 
    Age = c(9L, 10L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), Drug = c(0.885769541, 
    0.922067109, 0.893805474, 0.95573985, 0.965478738, 0.938519714, 
    0.923849826, 0.885100522, 0.915816548, 0.981582548, 1, 0.759658091, 
    0.952030932, 0.785710346, 0.940174245, 0.941247073, 0.979524863, 
    0.982821402, 0.985709539, 0.995845087)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

> summary(fake_a$Age)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   9.00   11.00   14.00   14.96   16.00   31.00 

> summary(fake_b$Age)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   9.00   19.75   28.00   24.85   31.00   31.00
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Why do you want to subsample (i.e., why not just use everyone and adjust for age down the line)? How many units do you want to remain in your subsample? What do you want the distribution of age to look like in the final sample?

Comment: Hi Thanks, 
So the idea is to select two subgroups (one from each of these populations) that are very similar in age to each other (same average age). ideally the age differences will not be significant between these groups so we will then collect further data just for those individuals. For this particular case, since the numbers are low I can see if I take only individuals older than ~17 years the averages and the median become similar. But I would like to find a way to do this not visually.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Is there maximum number of units you are allowed to retain (i.e., is there a maximum number of cases you are allowed to follow up on)? If it is possible to retain all units in one of the datasets, is that okay? Do the subgroups have to have equal numbers of units in them?

Comment: Yes, I could retain all units in one of the datasets. No maximum. I am actually very interested in the numbers of instances that are retained in each distribution since this will inform how many IDs will be available or my future study. And no the subgroups don't need to have the same number of units in them. I basically want all the instances  where an ID is retained  provided the age distribution of the new subsamples are statistically insignificant among each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. I'll describe a few that I think would be effective. Not all have been described in the literature, but that doesn't really matter since your primary task is to create two equivalent groups, and the performance of the methods can be evaluated based on their ability to do so. The three methods I'll describe are 1:1 matching, cardinality matching, and subset selection using the energy distance.

I'll demonstrate these using R. Let's say we have a dataset called `data_combined` which contains the two datasets stacked on top of each other and a new variable `data` identifying which dataset each comes from, with 1 being the smaller dataset and 0 being the larger.

#### 1:1 matching

In 1:1 matching, you create pairs of units, where each pair contains one member from one dataset and one member from the other. The units are paired based on their value of age, so the differences in age between pairs will be as small as possible. It is possible to restrict the differences between ages to be no larger than a given value by imposing a "caliper". There are multiple algorithms to perform the matching, but a good one is optimal matching, which minimizes the average within-pair distance across all pairs. Any units that do not receive a pair are dropped from the subsample. This will give you the same number of units from both datasets. If you use a caliper, you may end up discarding units from both datasets, whereas if you don't, only units from the larger dataset will fail to be matched. You can perform 1:1 matching using `MatchIt::matchit()` by supplying age as the `distance` value and setting `method = "optimal"`. If you want to use a caliper, you can do so with the `caliper` argument, but you have to set `method = "nearest"` to do nearest neighbor instead of optimal matching (this won't matter too much, especially with a caliper).

Here is some code to implement this:

```
m.out <- matchit(data ~ age, data = data_combined, distance = data_combined$age,
                 method = "nearest", caliper = c(age = 2), std.caliper = FALSE)
subsample <- match.data(m.out)
```

#### Cardinality matching

With cardinality matching, you find the largest subsample of units that satisfies a given balance (i.e., comparability) threshold. There are two ways to do this: classic cardinality matching and template matching. With classic cardinality matching, you must require that the sizes of the two subsamples are the same. With template matching, you choose a template distribution (i.e., one dataset, the other, or their combination) and the algorithm finds the largest subsample from each group that matches the template distribution. You need to supply a balance tolerance for this method, which is applied only to the mean. To ensure other features of the distribution are similar, you can supply balance tolerances to the square, cube, etc. of age and to binned versions of age. You can do this with `MatchIt::matchit()` by setting `method = "cardinality"`. See the documentation on how to choose between classic cardinality and template matching.

```
#Classic cardinality matching
m.out <- matchit(data ~ poly(age,4) + cut(age, 5), data = data_combined,
                 method = "cardinality", tols = .01, solver = "gurobi")
subsample <- match.data(m.out)
```

#### Subset selection using the energy distance

With subset election using the energy distance, you compute a general measure of the distance between the distributions of age in the two subsamples called the energy distance. You then drop one unit at a time, in particular, the unit that when dropped makes the energy distance the smallest. You can keep doing this until the energy distance doesn't get any smaller or you have dropped too many units. This creates a "frontier", i.e., a function with energy distance on the y-axis and the number of units dropped on the x-axis. You can stop at any point along the frontier and extract the matched subsample. This method uses the technology of the "matching frontier" as implemented in the `MatchingFrontier` R package, which you can install using `devtools::install_github("iqss/MatchingFrontier")`.

```
mf.out <- makeFrontier(data ~ age, data = data_combined,
                       QOI = "FSATE", metric = "energy")
plot(mf.out)
subsample <- generateDataset(mf.out, N = summary(mf.out)$N["best"])
```

Finally, to assess how similar the distributions of ages are, you can use functions in the `cobalt` package that were specifically designed to assess balance between distributions. `bal.plot()` displays a density plot of the two distributions; ideally they overlap. `bal.tab()` computes balance statistics.

Comment: That's amazing! I am going through it, I am having some problems with some packages that won't install in R version 4.0.3. Regarding the last solution I got these two errors : ``` Error: In makeFrontier(), QOI must be either 'FSATT' or 'SATT'.``` went away when I changed FSATE to FSATT and the second one
``` In makeFrontier(), metric must be either 'L1', 'Mahal', 'Euclid', or 'Custom'.```

Comment: You're dealing with an old version of `MatchingFrontier` then. Did you install it using the code I provided? All packages should work in R 4.0.3. If you get a warning like "package was built in version 4.1.0" you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

This question asks about R, but this is a pretty common problem in ML/stats. Here's a way to do it in Pandas:

```
from typing import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def values_dist(vals: Union[List, Tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series]) -> pd.Series:
    assert isinstance(vals, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series))
    val_counts: pd.Series = pd.Series(Counter(vals))  ## Includes nan and None as keys.
    return val_counts / val_counts.sum()

def sample_idxs_match_distribution(
        source: Union[List, Tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series],
        target: Union[List, Tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series],
        n: Optional[int] = None,
        seed: Optional[int] = None,
        shuffle: bool = True,
        target_is_dist: bool = False,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Values from current series based on another distribution, and return randomly-shuffled indexes from the source.
    Selecting these indexes will give a distribution from the source whicha matches that of the target distribution.
    """
    if not target_is_dist:
        target_prob_dist: pd.Series = values_dist(target)
    else:
        target_prob_dist: pd.Series = target
    assert isinstance(target_prob_dist, pd.Series)
    assert abs(float(target_prob_dist.sum()) - 1.0) <= 1e-2  ## Sum of probs should be exactly or very close to 1.

    assert isinstance(source, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series))
    source_vc: pd.Series = pd.Series(Counter(source))
    # print(f'\nsource_vc:\n{source_vc}')
    # print(f'\ntarget_prob_dist:\n{target_prob_dist}')
    missing_source_vals: Set = set(target_prob_dist.index) - set(source_vc.index)
    if len(missing_source_vals) > 0:
        raise ValueError(f'Cannot sample; the following values are missing in the source: {missing_source_vals}')

    n: int = get_default(n, len(source))
    max_n_sample: pd.Series = (source_vc / target_prob_dist).apply(
        lambda max_n_sample_category: min(max_n_sample_category, n),
    )
    # print(f'\n\nmax_n_sample:\n{max_n_sample}')
    max_n_sample: int = math.floor(min(max_n_sample.dropna()))
    # print(f'Max possible sample size: {max_n_sample}')
    source_value_wise_count_to_sample: pd.Series = (target_prob_dist * max_n_sample).round(0).astype(int)
    source_value_wise_count_to_sample: Dict[Any, int] = source_value_wise_count_to_sample.to_dict()
    ## Select random indexes:
    source_val_idxs: Dict[Any, List[int]] = {val: [] for val in source_vc.index}
    for idx, val in enumerate(source):
        if val in source_value_wise_count_to_sample:
            source_val_idxs[val].append(idx)
    sampled_idxs: np.array = np.array(flatten1d([
        random_sample(source_val_idxs[val], n=req_source_val_count, seed=seed)
        for val, req_source_val_count in source_value_wise_count_to_sample.items()
    ]))
    if shuffle:
        sampled_idxs: np.ndarray = np.random.RandomState(seed).permutation(sampled_idxs)
    return sampled_idxs
```

How to use:

- `source` should be your current pandas series, and target should be your target series.
- This function returns an array of indexes, which you can use to index your `source` via `source.iloc[fn_output]`. Pass `n` as the final size of data which you want.
- You can also pass `target_is_dist=True` if your `target` is already a distribution over the categories.
- `seed` for reproducibility.